# A-Frame Physics System Compound Colliders with Orientation Vectors

Tags: game-physics, collision, aframe

Using the A-Frame Physics System components provided [here](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system), I've been trying to create compound colliders similar to the examples in the documentation. However, the body shape seems to break and fall through the ground static body whenever I add an orientation vector to any of the colliders.

Any advice on how to implement rotated shapes into compound colliders using these components? It's been difficult to troubleshoot using the documented methodology; I've also considered creating separate entities and connecting them via lock constraints, but doing that has raised problems when there's excessive overlap between the separate entities.

Here's the initial implementation I was trying for one model, based on the documentation for the components:

```html
<a-entity gltf-model="#rams-horn" body="type: dynamic; shape: none; mass: 1;" id="ramsHorn" class="seed" position="0 5 0" scale="1 1 1" rotation="180 45 45"
                 shape__main="shape: sphere;
                              radius: 0.085;
                              offset: -0.145 0.136 0.165;"
                 shape__body1="shape: sphere;
                               radius: 0.06;
                               offset: -0.083 0.243 0.198;"
                 shape__body2="shape: sphere;
                               radius: 0.06;
                               offset: -0.173 0.029 0.118;"
                 shape__bodyTop="shape: box;
                                 halfExtents: 0.084 0.103 0.105;
                                 offset: -0.157 0.098 0.038;
                                 orientation: 48.823 151.396 128.878 1;"

                 shape__leftArm="shape: box;
                                 halfExtents: 0.137 0.0445 0.0325;
                                 offset: 0.005 -0.244 0.06;
                                 orientation: 14.802 -1.075 -11.758 1;"
                 shape__leftArm1="shape: box;
                                  halfExtents: 0.13 0.041 0.0305;
                                  offset: 0.249 -0.271 0.017;
                                  orientation: 4.774 21.49 5.687 1;"
                 shape__leftArm2="shape: box;
                                  halfExtents: 0.09 0.0365 0.02;
                                  offset: 0.412 -0.203 -0.073;
                                  orientation: -5.452 37.235 41.454 1;"
                 shape__leftArm3="shape: box;
                                  halfExtents: 0.0485 0.0305 0.02;
                                  offset: 0.482 -0.107 -0.142;
                                  orientation: -8.285 39.333 53.542 1;"
                 shape__leftArm4="shape: box;
                                  halfExtents: 0.091 0.0285 0.013;
                                  offset: 0.487 0.007 -0.18;
                                  orientation: -16.037 12.177 114.669 1;"

                 shape__rightArm="shape: box;
                                  halfExtents: 0.026 0.044 0.1045;
                                  offset: -0.171 -0.098 -0.15;
                                  orientation: 8.467 -17.253 -43.762 1;"
                 shape__rightArm1="shape: box;
                                   halfExtents: 0.12 0.0245 0.0355;
                                   offset: -0.073 -0.048 -0.325;
                                   orientation: -19.243 36.415 23.184 1;"
                 shape__rightArm2="shape: box;
                                   halfExtents: 0.1065 0.032 0.0205;
                                   offset: 0.092 0.02 -0.43;
                                   orientation: 72.192 124.564 108.909 1;"
                 shape__rightArm3="shape: box;
                                   halfExtents: 0.0865 0.025 0.0145;
                                   offset: 0.263 0.07 -0.436;
                                   orientation: 75.904 92.023 107.88 1;"
                 shape__rightArm4="shape: box;
                                   halfExtents: 0.0455 0.0165 0.0145;
                                   offset: 0.371 0.101 -0.386;
                                   orientation: 70.206 100.066 148.711 1;"
                 shape__rightArm5="shape: box;
                                   halfExtents: 0.0515 0.022 0.01;
                                   offset: 0.407 0.11 -0.31;
                                   orientation: 70.356 103.559 -174.73 1;" shadow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake *and* stupid first answer. The units for Quaternions in Three.js and CANNON.js are radians, but the conversion between Euler coordinates and *Quaternions* is also necessary. You could program a conversion tool or use the methods supported by the Quaternion class in CANNON.js; I used an [online calculator](https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/) because my collider was composed of just a few primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, using degrees for orientation rather than radians :( anyone else having similar issues should refer to the documentation for Quaternions in Three.js